# jquery code giving error (missing ) after argument list)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append a `script` to the head using the below code . But when I run the code the browser gives me below error. I don't see any syntax error in the code. Any clue on why this is happening?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after `argument` list

But, I don't see any missing ) after `argument` list

```
   $(head).append('<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=\'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl+ \'&gtm_auth=WarCuepLcL4AuvFBwaImrQ&gtm_preview=env-6&gtm_cookies_win=x\';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-xxxxx\');</' + 'script>');
```

EDIT: Below is the total code

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



            </head>
            <body>
            <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <script> 
            var head = $('head');

               $(head).append('<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=\'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl+ \'&gtm_auth=WarCuepLcL4AuvFBwaImrQ&gtm_preview=env-6&gtm_cookies_win=x\';f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-xxxxx\');</' + 'script>');   


            </script>
            <!-- Google Tag Manager -->


            Test Page
            </body>


            </html>
```

Comment: Why are inserting the code like that can't it be written straight forward

Comment: I'd bet it's the unescaped single quotes in the false portion of the shorthand if statement

Comment: You were correct Andy, it is unescaped single quotes. Thank you. It got fixed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(head).append('$$$$($$$$

You are not closing the Brace inside $$$$ above.
Please close it in the appropriate place and i haven't really tested the other code

Comment: I have manually checked it . No syntax errors. Can you please test in your local. I have posted the entire code

Answer (score -1):

just use this in a **`<script>`** tag

```js
(function(w, d, s, l, i) {
  w[l] = w[l] || [];
  w[l].push({
    'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
    event: 'gtm.js'
  });
  var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j = d.createElement(s),
    dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
  j.async = true;
  j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl + '&gtm_auth=WarCuepLcL4AuvFBwaImrQ&gtm_preview=env-6&gtm_cookies_win=x';
  f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
})(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-xxxxx');
```